# Common Lisp the Language: "dynamic shadowing cannot occur"

Tags: scope, lisp, common-lisp

Near the end of chapter 3 of Common Lisp the Language, Steele writes "Constructs that use lexical scope effectively generate a new name for each established entity on each execution. Therefore dynamic shadowing cannot occur (though lexical shadowing may)". I am confused as to what exactly he means by "dynamic shadowing cannot occur". What would an example of "dynamic shadowing" look like?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of what he might have meant:

```
(defun f (g)
  (let ((a 2))
    (funcall g a)))
(let ((a 1))
  (f (lambda (x) (- x a))))
```

This returns `1` in Common Lisp because the lexical binding of `a` in `f` does not affect the binding of `a` in the top-level `let`, so, when `f` calls `g`, it subtracts `1` from `2` because the `lambda` gets `a` from the top-level binding.

Contrast this with the dynamic binding in Emacs Lisp, where the return value is `0`.

You might also find it instructive to work out the [`contorted-example`](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node43.html) and try it in CL and ELisp.

Comment: I'm not so sure. You are demonstrating how a variable with lexical scope cannot be shadowed dynamically. He might be saying that, but he says unconditionally that "dynamic shadowing cannot occur".

Comment: He says that odd perfect number do not exist. I explain what a perfect number is and demonstrate an even one. You are now asking me to supply an odd perfect number as an example. I am confused. :-)

Comment: @malisp I also read it as "dynamic shadowing [of lexically scoped constructs] cannot occur".

Comment: @sds Steele saying that "dynamic shadowing cannot occur" is not equivalent to him saying an odd perfect number does not exist, it is more like him saying that perfect numbers do not exist. The interpretation m-n gave in which Steele is implicitly referring to a subset of dynamic scoping (equivalent to implicitly referring to odd perfect numbers) is a possibility. So I am asking what does Steele mean when he says "dynamic shadowing". I think what m-n says may be right, but to me it seems unlikely.

Comment: @mailsper "Dynamic shadowing" can only occur with variables that are declared "special" (that is, they're dynamically scoped, so that the binding closes to the evaluation site on the call stack is used). So with lexical variables, dynamoc shadowing *cannot* occur.